# Aligning the point cloud into corresponding 3D Plane (Building)

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry, buildings

I want to align the given 3D point clouds into their corresponding plane.

The corresponding plane is basically a 3D computer-made geometrical model of a Building (construction building with walls and roof plane only) and is developed according to the given point cloud. I want to align the point cloud with the model. The model can be in any format or it can also be converted into point clouds as well if the alignment demands. Any suggestions, please.

Comment: What is a "point cloud"?

Comment: points (x,y,z) in 3D space.

Comment: How the plane is defined? The classic equation? A point on the plane is one that satisfies the equation. Why this is not enough?

Comment: plane equation is ax+by+cz+d = 0, actually the points contain some outliers also, similarly the plane is a stl file while point cloud are available as simple xyz file

Comment: actually the problem I am facing is that data (point cloud) has many planes corresponding to its plane. Particularly, it's a small and simple building who has many planes, like a wall, and floors. Through SVD we can solve only for one plane, but i don't know how to solve when there is connection of planes.

Comment: What do you mean by connection of planes. Couls you have a drawing of your problem?

Comment: means that planes are connected with each other at corners